# How is a language's classification decided upon ? (or modified)

Tags: historical-linguistics, language-identification

If a new language is discovered or if a study shows that a certain language should be reclassified, is there a committee(s) that decides on this ? (who ?)

Comment: No, there is no politburo in linguistics, just communis opinio (achieved through scholarly discussion - at times very heated - in peer-reviewed journals, scholarly monographs and edited books, and sometimes conferences). And no one is forced to accept it anyway, even if it's generally accepted.

Comment: @AlexB. seems odd, how can such a consensus be measured ? (a conference would make sense, wouldn't be representative though )
And how does one exclude bias in such things ?!
Certain languages are considered holy, and any deviation would be rejected ...

Comment: @PrimataLógico Anyone can publish whatever nonsense they want. Either others will agree with it or they won't. After some time, the voice from that publication will be used by others in their publications or will be forgotten. Classifications disagreements are common and politically loaded. Are Serbian and Croatian two languages or is it Serbo-Croatian which is divided more on the Chakavian/Shtokavian/Kajkavian line? Is Rusyn a separate language or just a form of western Ukrainian?

Comment: ... Often the politicians  and the political views of the scholars in those countries determine it and the outside view can be different.

Comment: Why would anyone want "to measure" consensus? What matters is 1. how accurate you report language data ; 2. how convincing your analysis of the data is.

Comment: re: "Certain languages are considered holy, and any deviation would be rejected" - 'holy languages' is only a matter of consideration for a sociolinguist, to better understand how that language is used. But that does not make such languages immune to any critical scholarly analysis. I do linguistics, not theology.

Comment: @AlexB. just as VladimirF put it, there are political biases in numerous places ! This applies as well to the Arabic languages where Arabic is used as an umbrella term ... Ofc data is the arbiter but consider it as showing evidence for evolution and having a large part of the community reject it due to personal beliefs. You can't do much and as Vladimir said "*After some time, the voice from that publication will be used by others in their publications or will be forgotten*"

Comment: @AlexB. Yes I agree, but your "critical scholarly analysis" applies to you and your specialization ! I used the term "holy" to show bias ! An Arab linguist might might not be as critical & objective regarding Arabic as a linguist specializing in English !

Comment: 1. There's nothing that says if your L1 is Arabic, your specialization has to be Arabic. 2. Everyone is biased to a certain degree but see "communis opinio" above - and we all remember that Amicus Plato sed magis amica veritas. If someone calls themselves a linguist, it doesn't make them one, you **earn your reputation**. 3. I don't think this platform is primarily used for chatting, so I'm afraid I have to sign off. Cheers!